# How to calculate $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}pz}}{\sqrt{z}}\:\mathrm{d}z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to make Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, so I need to calculate this Integrl:

$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}pz}}{\sqrt{z}}\:\mathrm{d}z
$$

I use complex analysis to calculate. However, when I made secantlines at different positions on the complex plane, I got different answers. For example, when the secantline is on the lower half plane, the integral is $0$ when $p < 0$. But if the secantline is on the upper half plane, the integral is $0$ when $p > 0$, why?

Comment: How do you deal with negative values? In the context of your original problem, do you really want the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ ? Because the latter is easier to compute than the former.

Comment: I do want the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: what is your definition of $\sqrt{z}$ ? What argument do you choose?

Comment: Using the principal value for $\sqrt{z}$ when $z<0$, Maple gets $$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}pz}}{\sqrt{z}}\:\mathrm{d}z = 0$$ for all $p>0$ but for $p<0$ it gets $$\frac{(1-i)\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{p}}$$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, but I want to know how to calculate it.

Comment: @GEdgar What's the meaning of principal value for $\sqrt{z}$? Sorry for this but I'm a physical student and I don't know much math...

Comment: @badinmaths if $z = r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$, $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta/2}$, where $\theta \in [-\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$. Can I choose other values for $\theta$?

Comment: @badinmaths Why would you use anything other than the principal argument?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do : For $x > 0$, let $u = \sqrt{x}$ so $dx = 2udu$

$$\int_{0}^R \frac{e^{-ipx}}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R}} 2e^{-ipu^2}du$$

For $x < 0$, with your definition of $\sqrt{z}$ we have $\sqrt{x} = i\sqrt{-x}$ and we can define $u = \sqrt{-x}$ and $dx = -2udu$

$$\int_{-R}^0 \frac{e^{-ipx}}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_{-R}^0 \frac{e^{-ipx}}{i\sqrt{-x}}dx =  \int_{\sqrt{R}}^{0} 2ie^{ipu^2}du = -2i \int_0^{\sqrt{R}}e^{ipu^2}du$$

So we have to compute the Fresnel integral : $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{iau^2}du = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2|a|}}(1 + i \times sgn(a))$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know how to calculate it. However, there is a little mistake in the second part of the integral, it should be $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}pu^2}$